# How to update value of a map<int,vector<int>> in c++?

Tags: c++, hashmap

Given an array ar[]={10, 8, 3, 1, 3, 8, 2, 5, 8, 7};

The array is taken to be 1-based index.

Aim is to create a map, which stores all the indices of a particular element in a vector and hence the data structure `map<int, vector <int> >`

Here is what I am trying to do, if the key is already present in the map, then extracting the present value of vector and appending the current index to it, if not, then just pushing the current index and then inserting back to the map. For some reason the code is not doing what its supposed to do.

```
    map<int,vector<int>> m;
    for(int x=1;x<=n;x++){
        vector<int> v;
        if(m.find(ar[x])!=m.end()){
            v=m.at(ar[x]);
        }
        v.push_back(x);
        m.insert(make_pair(ar[x],v));
        printMap(m);
    }
```

Comment: Why not something simple like `m[ar[x]].push_back(x)`?

Comment: `std::map` is not implementes as a hash map. It's implemented as a tree data structure...

Comment: As for the problem you seem to have with the current code, you can't insert a key that already exists. If the key exists you must replace the data. Or as already mentioned, use the `[]` operator of the map to either insert (if the key doesn't exist) or update.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert it directly using `m [ arr[x] ].push_back(x)`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr {10, 8, 3, 1, 3, 8, 2, 5, 8, 7};

    std::map< int, std::vector<int> > m;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        m[ arr[i] ].push_back(i);
    }

    for (auto p : m)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " ";
        for (auto x : p.second)
            std::cout << x << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}
```